# Get the integer part of a Decimal field in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, integer, decimal, type-conversion

My question is very simple, but I couldn't find an answer. I'm sorry if it has been answered before.

I have a DecimalField which came from a view to my template in my django application.
I need to display only the integer part of it.

How can I do that?

========================= SOLUTION FOUND ========================

Sorry, I would have answered if I had permission, but only after 8 hours I can do so.

Thank you for the answers. I have found a builtin solution that worked just fine.
It is a builtin template filter. The documentation follows.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#floatformat

Basically, the usage for my purpose is something like this:

```
{{decimal_obj|floatformat:0}}
```

An even better solution is the stringformat filter:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#stringformat

Usage:

```
{{decimal_obj|stringformat:"d"}}
```

Thanks for the help. Ignacio was right ;)

Comment: 8 hours passed, now you can post this as an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only need to display the integral part of it then use a [`stringformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) of `"d"`. If you need to calculate it then do it in the view.

#### Example:

`{{ decimal_field | stringformat:'d' }}`

Comment: actually, a whole object -- with a DecimalField attribute -- comes from the view function, so in the template I have something like this: {{<my_object>.decimal_value}}. I need to add something to that expression to show only the integer part. I don't think I can use stringformat in this case. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Now I understood your answer. I'm sorry. It would be something like <decimal_obj>|stringformat:"d" right??? I'm adding it to the solutions. Acctually, it's much better. Thank you!